# Paramiko Expect (Huawei networks)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, paramiko, pexpect

I'm having issues with paramiko expect on *Huawei* equipment, this works perfectly on *cisco*, just to paint the picture...

I'm creating a simple SSH script where I am expecting the prompt at the end of every command given, again this is working perfectly on *cisco* where the prompt ends with a  `#`, so for instance `switch(config)#`, however the prompt on *huawei* equipment is encased in brackets like so `[switch]`

In *huawei* user mode the prompt is `<switch>` and paramiko expect works fine however in config mode with the brackets `[]` it just hangs and times out, could this be because of the square brackets? python thinks this is a list potentially?

```
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction
from os import system

system('cls')


IP = '192.168.5.2'
UN = 'username'
PW = 'password'
baseprompt = '<RICH_USG>'
sysprompt = str('[RICH_USG]')

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=IP, username=UN, password=PW)
session = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=5, display=True)
print('interactive SSH session established!')
session.expect(baseprompt)
print('DEBUG ------- Baseprompt found')

session.send('screen-length 0 temporary')
session.expect(baseprompt)


session.send('sys')
session.expect(sysprompt)  # This is where the script fails and times out


output = session.current_output_clean
ssh.close()

print(output)
```

any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with string `'[RICH_USG]'` is that `expect()` will use it as a regular expression to match against the input, and `[...]` is a special syntax which only matches a single of the given characters, eg just `R` or just `I`, and so on.

You need to remove any special meaning for `[` by escaping it with `\`. You don't need to escape `]`, but you can do so for symmetry. So your string should be `'\[RICH_USG]'`. To avoid unexpected consequences, it is usual to make this a raw string by prefixing an `r`, `r'\[RICH_USG]'`. Note that `expect()` will by default extend this to `r'.*\n\[RICH_USG]$'`, so your prompt must be at the start of a line, and include all the line.

Comment: Meuh, Many thanks for this comment, that was the issue, added the escape character and its now working fine, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Used encoding=latin-1 problem resolved,but
I couldn't verify expected values using paramiko . So I used SSHlibrary of ROBOT framework.
That worked fine for me